# how to get flip with css3 and change the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

my context
HTML

```
<div class="cart">
     <div class="black"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var whiteEl="<div class="white"></div>";
//I would like to replace black with white, flip animation.
$(".cart").empty().append(whiteEl);
whiteEl.addClass("flipanim");
```

css

```
@-webkit-keyframes flip{
    from{
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);           
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
  }
     /*
similar cross browser code*/

.flipanim{
    -webkit-animation: flip 1s 1;
    -moz-animation:flip 1s 1;
    -o-animation:flip 1s 1; 
    animation:flip 1s 1;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
   transition: all .5s;
}
```

I am using key frame animation for show transform animation.

and in javascript adding class to attached element.

my animation not working.

How can I add the new element with flip animation to ".cart"?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: animation not working

Comment: I would like to remove the old element and add new element with flip animation

Comment: Why remove the elements? You can have them coexist by initially flipping the second element by 180deg and declaring backface-visibility:none.

Comment: @Christoph I have to remove the element for further context.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(".cart").html('').append(whiteEl);
 //since you have already appended the created div here.. you can use class selctor.
 $('.white').addClass("flipanim");
```

Comment: I would like to remove the old element and add new element with flip animation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove any content for that and also don't need Javascript for it:

html-markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="cart">
         <div class="black">Black side</div>
         <div class="white">White side</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.cart div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cart .black {
    background:#111;
    color:white;
}
.cart .white {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  color: black;
  background: #eee;
}
```

Now you can apply your effects simply with:

```
.container:hover .cart {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Gnxhd/2)

Comment: you can safely omit the container, its just to make the animation less quirky.